# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c'の解決方法について

Tags: php, laravel

以下の環境でOracleに接続したいと思っております。

**環境**
・Windows 10
・Laravel 8
・PHP 8.0.1
・Apache 2.4
・instantclient 12.2

Oracleに接続するために、php.iniファイル内の以下のコメントを外しました。

**php.ini**

```
extension=oci8_12c
extension=pdo_oci
```

その後、php -vを実行したのですが、以下のエラーが発生します。
※PHP、instantclient12.2は64bit用のファイルをインストールしております。
※ちなみにinstantclient12.1を使用すると、以下のエラーは発生しません。

色々調べたのですが、解決方法が分かりません。
解決方法のご存知の方がいらっしゃれば、教えていただけますでしょうか。

**エラー**

```
C:\Users\meg>php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\PHP\php-8.0.1\ext\oci8_12c (指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。), C:\PHP\php-8.0.1\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\PHP\php-8.0.1\ext\oci8_12c (指定されたモジュ ールが見つかりません。), C:\PHP\php-8.0.1\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: C:\PHP\php-8.0.1\ext\pdo_oci (指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。), C:\PHP\php-8.0.1\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: C:\PHP\php-8.0.1\ext\pdo_oci (指定されたモジュー ルが見つかりません。), C:\PHP\php-8.0.1\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因が分かりましたので、報告いたします。

原因は Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable がインストールされていない為にエラーが発生しておりました。

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable をインストールしたところ、エラーが解決しました。

ありがとうございました。